# how to create a expandable modal in HTML bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I do have a modal that pops out when I click on the login button and it contains the form that I should insert my info in . On the other hand , I have another form which I don't want it to be visible at the beginning in the modal but if the user clicks on create an account instead of going to a new page I want to append that new form in the body of my modal . Is it possible if yes how ? Here is how my modal is coded at the time :

```
[![<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #222">
<div class="mu-title">
<span class="mu-subtitle">Login</span>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Body of the modal --> 
<div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #222">
<form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="login.php" novalidate="novalidate">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username" class="control-label" style="color: white">Username</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="" required="" title="Please enter you username" placeholder="username@siswa.um.edu.my">
<span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="password" class="control-label" style="color: white">Password</label>
                              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="" required="" title="Please enter your password">

                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <p style="color: white ">If you have forgatten your cridentials please feel free to contact  "018 316 0991"</p>

                          </div>





    </div>








    <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #222">


      <button type="submit" class="mu-readmore-btn">Login</button>

    </div>
    </form>
  </div>][1]][1]
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with ? Just append the register form to the modal body, just like you would append any other dom elements.

Comment: I'll be adding an option as I don't have account and then I want to form appears once the user clicks on that . Other wise I only want to login form to be there ;) @DavidDomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with show and hide of two forms in bootstrap modal.

Example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="row">
          <div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-12  col-sm-12 ">                    
            <div class="panel panel-info" >
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                        <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
                    </div>     

                    <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

                        <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
                            
                        <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                    
                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username or email">                                        
                                    </div>
                                
                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                        <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
                                    </div>
                                    

                                
                            <div class="input-group">
                                      <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                          <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                                        </label>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                      <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Login  </a>


                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                        <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                                            Don't have an account! 
                                        <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
                                            Sign Up Here
                                        </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                            </form>     



                        </div>                     
                    </div>  
        </div>
        <div id="signupbox" style="display:none; " class="mainbox col-md-12  col-sm-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">Sign Up</div>
                            <div style="float:right; font-size: 85%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a id="signinlink" href="#" onclick="$('#signupbox').hide(); $('#loginbox').show()">Sign In</a></div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="panel-body" >
                            <form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                
                                <div id="signupalert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <p>Error:</p>
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                                    
                                
                                  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="firstname" class="col-md-3 control-label">First Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lastname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwd" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="icode" class="col-md-3 control-label">Invitation Code</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="icode" placeholder="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->                                        
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                        <button id="btn-signup" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Sign Up</button>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                            </form>
                         </div>
                    </div>

               
               
                
         </div> 
        </div>
    </div> 
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```